# Get a custom identifier of a custom UITableViewCell from a button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an app that uses a custom `UITableViewCell` and a custom `UIButton`. The name of these are `CustomCell` and `CustomButton`.
The `CustomButton` and the `CustomCell` have a identifier. The `CustomButton` has `buttonIdentifier` and the `CustomCell` has `cellIdentifier`. When creating the table both of them get the same id. Also the cell has another custom attribute called `projectFullName`.

Example:

```
NSString *tempString    = @"temp"; // The content is always different
button.buttonIdentifier = tempString;
cell.cellIdentifier     = tempString;
cell.projectFullName    = @"temp"; // The content is always different
```

Now, what I want to do is, when I press the button, that I also get the content of the `textLabel` of the cell. So what I'm basically doing is.

```
-(void)editProject:(id)sender {
    stringEditIdentifier            = ((CustomButton *)sender).projectButtonIdentifier;
    UIAlertView *alertView          = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Projektname"
                                                             message:@""
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:@"Speichern", nil];
    [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    [alertView show];
}
```

But what I also want to do now is to prefill the input field by doing the following

`[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text = labelCellName;`

The `labelCellname` is the name of the text of the `textLabel` I assigned before. Since the `CustomCell` and the `CustomButton` have the same identifier I thought it would be fairly easy to get the content, but my app always crashes. This is what I tried.

**First try**

```
CustomButton *buttonTemporary   = (CustomButton *)sender;
CustomCell *cellTemporary       = (CustomCell *)[buttonTemporary superview];
NSString *labelCellName         = cellTemporary.projectFullName;
```

**Error**

```
UITableViewCellScrollView projectFullName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa895df0
2013-12-17 14:17:09.279 TodolistiOS[17702:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellScrollView projectFullName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa895df0'
```

**Second try**

```
int row                         = ((CustomButton *)sender).tag;
NSIndexPath* indexPath          = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]; // in case this row in in your first section
CustomCell* cell                = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *labelCellName         = cell.projectFullName;
```

**Error**

There is no error that the app crashes. But, if I have three entries in the `UITableView` that all have different names `labelCellName` is always the name of the first entry. So when I click on the `CustomButton` from the second entry I still get the name of the first entry. What am I doing wrong? I hope I have made enough information, since my last question wasn't so good.

**Third try**

```
CustomButton *button    = (CustomButton*)sender;
NSIndexPath *myIP       = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
CustomCell *cellT       = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
NSString *testTemp      = cellT.projectFullName;
NSLog (@"%@" , testTemp );
```

**Error**

Same as in second try

Also, when I do this

```
CustomButton *button    = (CustomButton*)sender;
NSLog ( @"%d", button.tag );
```

The button.tag is always empty. Is this, because I'm not setting it? If yes, how should I set it correctly? I mean, the value is dynamic, since I never know how many entries I will have! Is there no way to get it by the `cellIdentifier` and `buttonIdentifier` since they're the same anyway?

**Fourth try**

I now manually added a tag id to the buttons.

```
editButton.tag = tagCount;
tagCount       = tagCount+1;
```

This works until I add a new row to the `CustomCell` to the `UITableView`. Then the tagCount is messed up and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand fully but, can you give `CustomButton` an `IBOutlet` that points to its containing cell?  (Connected either in interface builder or code, depending on how you create the button/cell combination.)

Comment: I am not quite sure if i get what you mean. Do you tried setting the tag of the button to the index of the cell in cellForIndexPath and then later determine the textlabel of the cell by getting the cell at index button.tag ?

Comment: I never worked with `IBOutlet` so I don't think if that would be a way to go, since I have no idea about it. Can you give me a ressource where I could read and try out what you mean?

Comment: @DavidEhlen - Yes, I set the tag in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then inanother method I tried to get it

Answer (score 0):

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[[customCell button] setTag:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

when button is clicked get the cell and the text of the textlabel:

```
UITableViewCell cell = [(UITableViewCell *)[(UITableView *)self  cellForRowAtIndexPath:   [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0]];

NSString *text = [cell yourLabel].text;
```

Of course you would have to define your button and your label as property in your uitableviewcell class.

Comment: Hi. The button is not in the cell. It's a `subView` but I can't access it with `cell.button.tag` - It's an own button that is from the class `CustomButton`

Comment: Well you could retrieve the button and the textfield with `UITextField *getTextView = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:200];` and then just set the tag of the textfield to 200. then you wouldn't use the tag after that like i mentioned in my answer but you have access to the components and could proceed with that.

Comment: The problem here would be, that firstly it is a `UILabel` not a `UITextField` - Ok, no real problem here, but anyway. The other one, would be, that I can't set the tag to something because I can't set the tag. The tag has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I now managed to do an own solution. But this doesn't seem right. I'm using a for-loop to iterate through every `CustomCell` in my `UITableView`. But when I have 1000 entries this could be a performance problem wouldn't it?

```
stringEditIdentifier            = ((CustomButton *)sender).projectButtonIdentifier;
NSString *labelCellText         = @"";

for(int i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++)
{
    NSIndexPath *index          = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i  inSection:0];
    CustomCell *cell            = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
    NSString *textFieldVal      = [cell.textLabel text];
    NSString *cellIdentifier    = cell.projectCellIdentifier;

    if ( [cellIdentifier isEqualToString:stringEditIdentifier ] ){
        labelCellText     = textFieldVal;
    }

}
UIAlertView *alertView          = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Projektname"
                                                              message:@""
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Speichern", nil];

[alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text = labelCellText;
[alertView show];
```

Comment: you could add a identifier to both your uitextfield and your uibutton.then also add some random tags to both of them. i cellForRowAtIndexPath get the controls by their tags and set the identifiers. then use the identifiers for retrieving the text.

Comment: anyway just trigger the action if the cell is clicked via didSelectRowAtIndexPath is no option ?